# I paid R3999 for registration R4,799.05 for IMF now R3,768 for C.O.T is this not a scam? They will need another money after this?

Tags: india, scams, credit

I apply for a loan I  pay 3999 for registration after IMF of R4,799.05 now I must pay  R3 768 for C.O.T and they say I will get the money back is this not a scam?

Comment: Who are "they"?

Comment: Please add some more detail and information. How much is the loan amount? What is IMF?  International Monetary Fund?

Comment: If someone is asking you for a fee to transfer money, it's almost assuredly a scam.  If it wasn't a scam, they'd simply deduct the fee from the money they're sending you.

Comment: If you keep paying, they will keep finding new tings you need to pay for.

Comment: If you give me R4621 I will tell you the answer. (this is a joke, don't do it)